# error de conexión local

Tags: php

Hola amigos del foro esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, les comento que estoy desarrollando mi primera aplicación en android studio, antes de finalizar la de java a través de netbeans 12.0, el cual ahora quiero llevarlo a android studio, he realizado el siguiente código para la búsqueda de datos, sin antes de realizar la conexión, este es el código que utilizo para la conexión ambos funcionan muy bien y no dan error.

```
<?php
$hostname='localhost';
$database='oficina';
$username='root';
$password='';
$conexion=new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
if($conexion->connect_errno){
echo "El sitio web esta experimentado problemas";
$conexion=new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
}
?>
```

y el otro que utilizo:

```
<?php
function retornarConexion(){
$_SERVER ="localhost";
$usuario ="root";
$clave ="";
$base = "oficina";
$con = mysqli_connect ($_SERVER, $usuario, $clave, $base) or die ("Problemas");
mysqli_set_charset ($con, "UTF8");
return $con;
}
?>
```

la versión que estoy utilizando en visual studio code actualmente es 1.67, anteriormente estaba utilizando la versión 1.60, por la cual la actualice, al igual que el postmann tambian actualizados con la ultima versión. este es el código que utilizo para la búsqueda de datos:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require("conexion1.php");
$conexion = retornarConexion();
$datos = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT 
ID,Fecha_Denuncia,Fecha_Siniestro,N_Siniestro,Descripcion,Nombre_Conductor,Rut_Conductor,Patente_Vehiculo,Nombre_Tercero,Patente_Tercero,Nombre_Compania,Inspeccion,Nombre_Asegurado,Rut_Asegurado,N_Poliza,Tipo_Seguro,Analista,Perdida,
Fecha_Designacion,Monto_Perdida,Fecha_Informe,Inspector,Activo from casos where ID=$_GET[ID]");
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($datos, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

y este es el otro código que utilizo para la búsqueda de datos en otra tabla:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$Nombre = $_GET ['Nombre_Corredor'];
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM corredores WHERE Nombre_Corredor = '$Nombre'";
$resultado = $conexion -> query ($consulta);
while ($fila = $resultado -> fetch_array()){
$corredores []= array_map ('utf8_encode', $fila);
}
echo json_encode($corredores);
$resultado -> close();
?>
```

al probarlos a través de postmann cuya versión es la 9.22, que es lo que recomiendan a través de la web.

```
http://localhost/oficina/buscar_casos?ID=1000
```

al momento de hacer el ejecutar me manda este error, lo cual trato de buscar y siempre dicen que el error es del puerto 80: el cual lo utiliza el phpmyadmin a través del mysql, y no registra problemas, este es el error.

```
<address>Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/7.4.29 Server at 192.168.1.96 Port 80</address>
```

por lo cual no se si el error se genera a través de la conexión realizada o a través del código del buscar, busque a través de la web y del puerto hablan pero se supone que el puerto 80 lo ocupa el servidor local xampp y no me da problema, ya que cuando lo ejecuto en netbeans 12.0, no me da problemas, además hace dos semanas atrás funcionaba muy bien y cuando actualice windows y a su vez postmann y visual studio code me empezó a dar este problema, como lo soluciono desinstalo visual studio code, postmann y android studio para que lo realicen de nuevo y empezar desde cero nuevamente, como soy nuevo en estas lides favor de su ayuda y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Eso no parece un error, más bien parecería que está interpretando mal un archivo de configuración. ¿Has probado la URL en el navegador directamente: `http://localhost/oficina/buscar_casos?ID=1000`?

Comment: @A.Cedano te comento que lo realice y me sale lo mismo que en postamn "The requested URL was not found on this server." y "Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/7.4.29 Server at localhost Port 80", ayer en la noche me dedique a investigar y varios les ha pasado lo mismo lo cual informan que hay que desinstalar xammp, visual studio code, postmann, android studio y netbeans y empezar todo desde cero, es decir, instalar xamp primero, después android studio, posteriormente visual studio code y postmann, que opinas?

Comment: Pues pues no estoy seguro que haya que desintalar todo. Parece ser que esa URL no existe realmente, o que estás intentando implementar URL amigables con una configuración errónea en `.htaccess` o, en el peor de los casos, que tu servidor está mal instalado/configurado, en cuyo caso habría que verificar tu instalación de Xammp, y configurar bien el servidor.

Comment: @A.Cedano  muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero trate de solucionarlo y no pude lo que hice desinstale solo xampp y volví a cargar la base de datos y me vuelve a dar el mismo error que no encuentra, pero ejecuto nuevamente el mismo programa a través de netbeans y no hay problema, no se en donde esta el error, ahora no se si esta con problemas esta parte en php, me imagino que en android no va a funcionar tampoco